# PowerShell String Matching and the Pipe Character

Tags: regex, string, powershell, matching

I am having difficulty matching strings in PowerShell that contain the pipe characters. Match returns true in the following scenario when it shouldn't:

```
> "Debug|x86" -match "Debug|x128"
True
```

I have tried escaping the match argument pipe character, but this doesn't change the unexpected result, e.g:

```
> "Debug|x86" -match "Debug`|x128" 
True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a regular expression so needs to be escaped with backslash, not PowerShell's backtick, e.g.:

```
> "Debug|x86" -match "Debug\|x128" 
False
```

As it is a regular expression, If the pipe character is not escaped, it evaluates to "Debug or x128".

Answer (score 9):

If you're not sure which characters you need to escape, let the Escape method do the work for you:

```
PS > [regex]::escape("Debug|x128")

Debug\|x128
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Chibacity and Shay have revealed the proper way to escape the meta-character in your regular expression. But if you want to understand more about the -match operator and other string comparison operators, you may find this article helpful:
[Harnessing PowerShell's String Comparison and List-Filtering Features](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/harnessing-powershells-string-comparison-and-list-filtering-features/). It comes complete with a one-page wallchart enumerating the various operators in both scalar and array context. Here's a preview:
[image]